# show following error for using parse.com data cloude Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

Tags: java, android, android-studio, parse-platform

please give me a solution 
Error Details :

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

[the link have my app all screen short java and xml](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/parse-developers/-agMdwEQqb4)

Answer (score 1):

This typically happens when you have duplicate Jars, try to locate the one of the jars and delete it. Then try again.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I tried to run the application in the device.
But everything is fine and no error if I clean or build the app.

In my case the same error found when added library size is larger than 65K.

I added the full play-service library in gradle along with some other library files instead the specific library.

After adding the specific library which I needed, my application running fine.

You can find how to add specific play-service library that you need to your project in this link [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

May be this will help you. Good luck and happy codding. :)